# Issues with moving WordPress folder to var/www/html (before/after)

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to install WordPress on my virtual machine following the official guide at [here](https://www.atlantic.net/vps-hosting/how-to-install-wordpress-ubuntu-14/)

Somehow I could not move my wordpress file to the respective folder var/www/html.

The following error are given.

```
cp: cannot stat ‘~r’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/var/www/html/index.php’: Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/var/www/html/license.txt’: Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/var/www/html/readme.html’: Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/var/www/html/wp-activate.php’: Permission denied
cp: omitting directory ‘/home/caleb/wordpress/wp-admin’
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/var/www/html/wp-blog-header.php’: Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/var/www/html/wp-comments-post.php’: Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/var/www/html/wp-config.php’: Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/var/www/html/wp-config.php~’: Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/var/www/html/wp-config-sample.php’: Permission denied
cp: omitting directory ‘/home/caleb/wordpress/wp-content’
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/var/www/html/wp-cron.php’: Permission denied
cp: omitting directory ‘/home/caleb/wordpress/wp-includes’
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/var/www/html/wp-links-opml.php’: Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/var/www/html/wp-load.php’: Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/var/www/html/wp-login.php’: Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/var/www/html/wp-mail.php’: Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/var/www/html/wp-settings.php’: Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/var/www/html/wp-signup.php’: Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/var/www/html/wp-trackback.php’: Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/var/www/html/xmlrpc.php’: Permission denied
```

So after checking the location, I found that I don't have a var/www/html folder due to me removing apache2 previously in a [LEMP installation guide](https://www.atlantic.net/vps-hosting/how-to-install-lemp-ubuntu-14-04/).

So I tried to reinstall apache via

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

After installing, I found that the var/www/html is now available. But still I could not copy the files into the respective folder without using sudo, which is not mentioned in the guide. After copying the files into the var/www/html directory, I am supposed to access my IP address to continue with WordPress installation. Which I failed as well, as the browser directed me to Nginx just like in the LEMP guide instead of WordPress installation page in the WordPress guide. Any idea?

Edit: Tried stopping Nginx service and it does not work. (Does not redirect me to WordPress page)

TL/DR: WordPress folder does not move to var/www/html like how the guide did, and after using sudo to move the folder, localhost does not go to WordPress installation page.

Answer (score 2):

You *should* have to use sudo to move anything into /var/www/html/.

Use `mv` not `cp`

```
sudo mv /example.com /var/www/html/
```

Comment: it's alright, I don't mind. As for the sudo command, I did attempt it with sudo as mentioned at the end.  Tto prevent errors, I used the cp command without sudo as shown in guide in the beginning, which gives the error as shown above.

Comment: Anyhow I have managed to solve it, There's a similar issues in ubuntu 18.04 as well. Turns out the guide is slightly outdated and I had to make some changes and install extra packages to make it work